# CSS styles is not being applied to PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, css, pdf, itext

I am having Problem in generating Pdf using itextsharp.

Here is my code . Please give Solutions.. My pdf is successfully generated but the style is missing. html generated is generating with style in browser. A hidden field value hdnTableval.Value contains the table with data ,to which style is to be applied

```
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            string css=@"<style type='TEXT/CSS'>TABLE{BORDER: 1PX SOLID #DDDDDD;MARGIN: 0;PADDING: 5;WIDTH: 100%;}TH{FONT-SIZE:      13PX;COLOR: #999;BORDER-BOTTOM: 1PX SOLID #DDDDDD;BORDER-RIGHT: NONE;BORDER-LEFT: NONE;TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER;PADDING-TOP: 8PX;PADDING-BOTTOM: 8PX;FONT-WEIGHT: BOLD;} TD {FONT-SIZE: 13PX;COLOR: #000;BORDER-BOTTOM: 1PX SOLID #DDDDDD;BORDER-RIGHT: NONE;BORDER-LEFT: NONE;TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER;PADDING-TOP: 8PX;PADDING-BOTTOM: 8PX;}TD.TDSEL{BACKGROUND: #FFFF99;}TH{BACKGROUND: #CECECE;}</style>";
            message.Append("<HTML><head>"+css);


            message.Append(@"</head><BODY>");

            message.Append(hdnTableval.Value.Trim());
            message.Append("</BODY></HTML>");

            Document document = new Document();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            document.Open();

            string htmlText = message.ToString(); // here give HTML

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(htmlText));

            document.Close();

            byte[] stream = ms.ToArray();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            //Write the file content directly to the HTTP content output stream.

            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Also. Image is not displayed in pdf accurately.. even if i give large width, it only displays in a small square box.

```
                    string imgPath = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "img/" + image;
                head.Append(@"<img height='100' width='703' style='margin:0 auto; display:block;' src='" + imgPath + "' alt='Header Missing' height='42' width='42' />");
```

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: And what is the content of "hdnTableval"?

Comment: itext sharp v2.0.50727. and HdnTableVal Contains an Html table with data

Comment: Style issue is solved. I change the CSS in BOLD to Normal.. that was the only difference. but image is still dispalying small.